# Usar "WHERE" como subquery con INSERT

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, insert

Mi idea es poder insertar la suma entre `2018-07-12`  y 9 días (`SELECT "" + interval 9 day)`) en la columna `fechaFin` de la misma tabla.

Pero primero quiero identificar una fila de `T_tarifa` con `where` pero no esta permitido.

¿Hay alguna forma diferente de poder hacer lo mismo? ¿No se puede usar el `where` despues de una operacion con parentesis ?

```
insert into T_tarifa (fechaFin)  values  (SELECT "2018-07-12" + interval 9 day) where regimen="desayuno
```

> Resuelto:

```
INSERT INTO T_tarifa (precioNoche,fechaInicio,fechaFin,tarifa) values ((SELECT precio  FROM T_tiphab  where codHotel="1" and tipo="camasimple"),"2018-11-01",( "2018-11-01" + interval 9 day),4  * (select precio from T_tiphab where tipo="camasimple" and codHotel= 1));
```

Comment: ¿El registro ya existe? Lo pregunto porque da la impresión que quieres modificar un campo solo, no todo un registro. Si ese fuera el caso ¿no debieras usar `UPDATE` en lugar de `INSERT` ? Ahora, si la tabla tiene un solo campo, el `INSERT` estaría bien, claro. Pero en Mysql, la forma de sumar intervalos es con la función `DATEADD`. 
 [Checa la documentación aquí](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Answer (score 3):

No se entiende bien lo que querés hacer.
Si lo que querés hacer, es modificar registros que ya existen en la tabla `T_tarifa`, la sentencia debería ser `UPDATE`.

```
UPDATE T_tarifa set fechaFin = (SELECT "2018-07-12" + interval 9 day as fechaFin) WHERE regimen="desayuno"
```

Si, en cambio, lo que querés hacer es aplicar un filtro sobre el `SUB SELECT` que va a insertar los datos en la tabla `T_tafifa`, deberías sacarle el paréntesis y hacer un `INSERT .. SELECT` normal.

Ahora bien: el campo `regimen` que pusiste en el `WHERE` no existe en la tabla generada por `SELECT "2018-07-12" + interval 9 day`, y por ende, te va a romper.

La sentencia `INSERT` se aplica sobre registros que todavía no existen en la base de datos (esto es, crea registros nuevos). Por ende, `INSERT ... WHERE` no tiene lógica.

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo realmente lo que quieres hacer, pero para realizar la suma de las Fechas creo que esto te puede servir:

```
Select DateAdd(Day, 9, '2018-07-12')
```